# Add or remove tooltip in Vuejs using Bootsrap vue

Tags: vuejs2, tooltip, bootstrap-vue

I have wirte a line code usse v-b-tooltip of Bootstrap Vue. However I only want to have tooltip in some condition. How can I set condition to have tooltip or not.

```
<b-btn v-b-tooltip="'Tooltip'">
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to disable tooltip is to have a "b-tooltip" element. Something like this:

```
<b-btn id="my-button">OK</b-btn>
<b-tooltip :disabled.sync="disableTooltip" target="my-button">Tooltip</b-tooltip>

<b-btn @click="disableTooltip = !disableTooltip">Enable / Disable Tooltip</b-btn>
```

Make sure you have the "disableTooltip" property in your data object.

More information:

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tooltip/#programmatically-disabling-tooltip

Answer (score 1):

> Disabling and enabling tooltips via $root events
>   You can disable all open tooltips by emitting the bv::disable::tooltip event on $root:

`this.$root.$emit('bv::disable::tooltip');`

> To disable a specific tooltip, pass the trigger element's id as the first argument:

`this.$root.$emit('bv::disable::tooltip', 'my-trigger-button-id');`

[Here the Doc with more examples](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/directives/tooltip/)